# @BASE_DIR@/install.log (No such file or directory) while doing openam setup for SSO

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, openam

We build SSO APP(SP) using SAML. For the testing, I want to setup an IDP to use openam([forgerock openam](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Deploy+OpenAM)) as IDP. While trying to configure I got below error in tomcat error log file(catalina.out).

**@BASE_DIR@/install.log (No such file or directory)**

[image]

Tried below Configuration but din't work

**Apache-tomcat 6.0.32 with OpenAm  : 10.0.0**

**Apache-tomcat 7.0.72 with OpenAm  : 9.5.2.rc1**

Question?

How to fix this issue?

Where can I configure parameter @BASE_DIR@ with a correct directory value?

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The @BASE_DIR@ issue is a really [old bug](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-2619), I would suggest to try to use a newer version. Both 9.5.x and 10.0.x versions are now [fully EOSL](https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a18529200).